# SUM value is same in Power pivot

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, powerpivot, datamodel

I want to calculate the sum of prescription projection value against each manufacturer. but the values are same for each manufacturer.

I have two fact table. (FactPrescriptionProjection,FactPrescriptionProduct)
In FactPrescriptionProjection records are unique.
In FactPrescriptionProduct product details are stored with 'FactPrescriptionProjection'[PrescriptionProjectionID] which can be multiple.

This is why because when a doctor write a medical prescription he can prescribe multiple medicine hence the presribed product (medicine) are stored in separate table with prescription's unique id.

Please find below sample file to understand the data model.

[Sample File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvZUqpXgHxIVzSISOI-gfVEP98oQ?e=96isfE)

Comment: What about the relations between tables, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @Gigga
I have given a link to download the  pbix sample file.

Comment: The link takes me to an Excel file? It might have the datamodel behind it, but it would be easier if you just posted a screenshot from the relations-tab in Power BI Desktop